# Can I assign a Random Engine to a variable without having template vars everywhere?

Tags: c++, random

I want to assign a random engine to a variable.

Underlying reason: I want to be able to switch the random engine between tests and production code. Tests should use a more predictable random generator than the production code.

Using the example code below it works, but I have to drag that `<T>` through all of my code, which I do not want to.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

class MyEngine {
public:
    typedef int result_type;

    result_type operator()() {
        return 42;
    }

    constexpr result_type min() {
        return 0;
    }

    constexpr result_type max() {
        return 100;
    }
};

template <class T>
struct EngineHolder {
    T engine;

    EngineHolder(const T& engine) : engine(engine) { }
};


//template <class T>
void doSomeWork(EngineHolder/*<T>*/* engineHolder) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(30, 50);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int v = distribution(engineHolder->engine);
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    // Engine 1
    std::default_random_engine engine1;
    EngineHolder<std::default_random_engine> foo1(engine1);
    doSomeWork(&foo1);

    // Engine 2
    std::default_random_engine engine2(145457);
    EngineHolder<std::default_random_engine> foo2(engine2);
    doSomeWork(&foo2);

    // Engine 3
    std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 1, 1, 10> engine3;
    EngineHolder<std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 1, 1, 10>> foo3(engine3);
    doSomeWork(&foo3);

    // My Engine
    MyEngine myEngine;
    EngineHolder<MyEngine> foo4(myEngine);
    doSomeWork(&foo4);

    return 0;
}
```

I thought of making the preprocessor do the trick by defining a macro which engine to use.
Now I am wondering is there yet another way?

Comment: If you don't want template, you may use interface instead.

Comment: Can you clarify? You can drop the `<T>` if you _know_ the type e.g. `doSomeWork(EngineHolder<std::uniform_int_distribution> engineHolder)`. If you want to keep it generic, you can't, of course.

Comment: @Jarod42 The engines don't have an interface, do they?

Comment: @black I don't know it, or more precise: I want to fill in different types as I please.

Comment: No, but you may add a layer do have one (as you add `EngineHolder<T>`, you may add some `IEngineHolder` which respect [UniformRandomNumberGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomNumberGenerator)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to [`uniform_int_distribution::operator()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()) makes very few demands on the parameter, detailed as [UniformRandomNumberGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomNumberGenerator). It must supply the members `result_type`, `min()`, `max()`, and `operator()()`. You've done that with your template class.

You can create an interface that contains those methods, and pass that interface into `doSomeWork` without needing a template. The concrete `EngineHolder` classes will derive from the interface. The only restriction is that you can't make a `typedef` virtual, so all the derived classes must use the same `result_type`.

```
class EngineHolderInterface {
public:
    typedef int result_type;

    virtual ~EngineHolderInterface() {};
    virtual result_type operator()() = 0;
    virtual result_type min() = 0;
    virtual result_type max() = 0;
};


template <class T>
struct EngineHolder : public EngineHolderInterface {
    T engine;

    EngineHolder(const T& engine) : engine(engine) { }
    virtual result_type operator()() { return engine(); }
    virtual result_type min() { return engine.min(); }
    virtual result_type max() { return engine.max(); }
};

void doSomeWork(EngineHolderInterface* engineHolder) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(30, 50);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int v = distribution(*engineHolder);
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You may even add something like: `static_assert(std::is_same<int, typename T::result_type>::value, "Engine is incompatible with interface")`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want a way to pass any type of random number generator to `doSomeWork`.  If that is the case I would simply template the function like

```
template <class Engine>
void doSomeWork(Engine engine) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(30, 50);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        int v = distribution(engine);
        std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And then you can use it like

```
// Engine 1
std::default_random_engine engine1;
doSomeWork(engine1);

// Engine 2
std::default_random_engine engine2(145457);
doSomeWork(engine2);

// Engine 3
std::linear_congruential_engine<unsigned int, 1, 1, 10> engine3;
doSomeWork(engine3);

// My Engine
MyEngine myEngine;
doSomeWork(myEngine);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c94336ba4482b3e)</kbd>

And now you do not have to specify the template type at all.

Comment: You just removed the struct in between, I do need. The template type is still there, you called it `<class Engine>`. I want to get rid of it on `doSomeWork()`. This function symbolizes the whole application.

Comment: @theHacker Okay.  I was not sure what you really wanted so I wanted to make sure you knew this could be done.